# Can only add one param to Bundle before facebook request

Tags: android, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, bundle

I am messing around with the facebook graph api for the first time and ran into an issue that doesn't to be happening to anyone else. If this is a duplicate, I apologize.

```
Bundle searchParams = new Bundle();
searchParams.putString("q", "coffee");
searchParams.putString("type", "place");

String response = facebook.request("search", searchParams);
```

In the above code, I am attempting to duplicate the example facebook has on their developer graph api page where they search for coffee places. The interesting thing that happens is when I pass in the Bundle, I have those two params that I have set.

```
public String request(String graphPath, Bundle params, String httpMethod)
        throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    params.putString("format", "json");
    if (isSessionValid()) {
        params.putString(TOKEN, getAccessToken());
    }
    String url = (graphPath != null) ? GRAPH_BASE_URL + graphPath
                                     : RESTSERVER_URL;
    return Util.openUrl(url, httpMethod, params);
}
```

As I step through the facebook request function (seen above), I noticed that the first param I put was popped out of the Bundle after the access_token was put in. This resulted in my Bundle containing only {"type", "place"}, and facebook's params. Through the debugger I noticed that the threshold was set to 3. I'm guessing that's my issue, but don't know how or where to change that.

Any thoughts?

Update:
I haven't been able to figure the issue out that I had. But was able to do what I needed when upgrading to facebook sdk 3.0b. Thanks.

Comment: Is this with the new Facebook SDK 3.0b for Android (https://developers.facebook.com/android/), or v2?

Comment: This is not the new 3.0b. I downloaded the Facebook SDK from their git site, maybe 2 weeks ago. I should also mention, I'm developing for Android 2.3.3. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do this and I call the request function like this.

```
String response = facebook.request("search", searchParams,"GET");
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what has caused that. I have upgraded to the new Facebook SDK and not having issues with it at all. I would recommend the new 3.0b to anyone starting a new app or upgrading if you have an old one. It is much more intuitive and they take care of so much for you.